# String Sort With Merge Sort

Tags: c, string, merge, mergesort

I am trying to do a string sort using merge sort algorithm. Here is my related code:

```
void sortCities(EXPEDITION *expedition, int expeditionNumber)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    char **tmp;
    tmp = (char**)malloc((expeditionNumber) * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < expeditionNumber; i++) {
        tmp[i] = (char*)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
    }
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < expeditionNumber; i++, j++) {
        tmp[j] = expedition[i].city;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < expeditionNumber; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", tmp[i]);
    }
    mergeSort(tmp, 0, expeditionNumber);
    for (i = 0; i < expeditionNumber; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", tmp[i]);
    }
}

void mergeSort(char** array, int first, int last)
{
    int middle;
    if (first < last) {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        mergeSort(array, first, middle);
        mergeSort(array, middle + 1, last);
        merge(array, first, middle + 1, middle, last);
    }
}

void merge(char** array, int first1, int first2, int last1, int last2)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    char **newArray;
    newArray = (char**)malloc((last2 - first1 + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < last2 - first1 + 1; i++) {
        newArray[i] = (char*)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
    }
    j = first2;
    i = first1;
    k = 0;
    while (i < last1 && j < last2) {
        if (strcmp(array[i], array[j]) > 0) {
            strcpy(newArray[k++], array[j++]);
        }
        else {
            strcpy(newArray[k++], array[i++]);
        }
    }
    if (i < last1) {
        while (i < last1) {
            strcpy(newArray[k++], array[i++]);
        }
    }
    if (j < last2) {
        while (j < last2) {
            strcpy(newArray[k++], array[j++]);
        }
    }
    for (i = first1, j = 0; i < last2; i++, j++) {
        strcpy(array[i], newArray[j]);
    }
}
```

The problem is tmp is returning with null values to sortCities function. I checked the content of the tmp before I sent it to mergeSort and I saw that it copied right(from expedition.city). What can be the reason?

Edit: I handled that by writing "array[i] = newArray[j];" insead "strcpy(array[i], newArray[j])". But now it does not sort correctly. I think I should use "<=" instead "<" but this time it stopped executing because of the limits of pointer arrays I guess.

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code, line by line, in a debugger to make sure it really does what you intend for it to do? I suggest you take a little time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Actually this is not that short, Its about 1000 lines. And yes I tryed another debugging approach which is taking in the pieces of code comment line, so I can see what is going wrong and what did I got truely by printing out as I did here in the sortCities function. Thanks

Comment: Well, if you want help you need to provide a [mcve], your question is incomplete, we don't know the structure of your data, or how you affect it, etc. Your problem could be anywhere in your program.

Comment: @Stargateur Expedition includes two char array for time and cities If you ask for it. In the sortCities functions, I printed out the tmp array before and after sending it to the mergeSort function. There is no problem before it went to mergeSort. After it, content of the tmp array is deleted. So this part of code does not related with any other part.

Comment: Even if it was a million lines of code, the correct solution is still to step through it with a debugger. You can start with "printf debugging" (a.k.a. tracing) to narrow down the sections of code you need to debug, but in the end the best way is to put in a breakpoint, and step through the code line by line. Debugging isn't easy, often quite the opposite. Unfortunately it's a required skill even if just programming as a hobby, and even more so if it's your job.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the information, I am gonna try now.

Comment: Note that you have redundant `if` statements around loops at `if (j < last2) {
        while (j < last2) {
            strcpy(newArray[k++], array[j++]);
        }
    }`  — simply remove the `if` because the loop will do nothing if the `if` would fail.

Comment: Note too that you're leaking memory at: `for (i = 0; i < expeditionNumber; i++) {
        tmp[i] = (char*)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
    }
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < expeditionNumber; i++, j++) {
        tmp[j] = expedition[i].city;
    }` — in the first loop, you allocate memory referenced by the `tmp[i]` pointers; in the second, you overwrite the only reference to the memory with the values in `expedition[i].city`, throwing away the memory.  You can't copy strings with assignment in C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, I actually wanted to write else statement against second if but I missed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Overwriting references can work too I guess. I can not see any problem with that. And I also tryed strcpy function instead just copying references but it gave the same problem as well.

Comment: Yes, overwriting the references 'works', but it leaks memory.  That is wasteful if your program will run for any length of time, or repeatedly sort the data.  It isn't clear whether you need to allocate the memory as shown.  You could simply allocate the array of pointers to pointers (first `malloc()`) and then copy the pointers from the data, and do your sorting and printing.  You should either free the space pointed at by `tmp` or return it lest you leak that memory (you leak it too, though not quite so egregiously, at the moment).  Use [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) if possible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the reply. Now I see the leaks. I used normal arrays instead pointer arrays and It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used normal char matrix (char[][N]) instead pointer matrix and it worked. Here is my new code:

```
void merge(char array[100][15],int first1,int first2,int last1,int last2){
int i;
int j;
int k;
char **newArray;
newArray=(char **)malloc((last2-first1+1)*sizeof(char *));
for(i=0;i<last2-first1+1;i++){
    newArray[i]=(char *)malloc(15*sizeof(char));
}
j=first2; 
i=first1; 
k=0;
while(i<=last1 && j<=last2){

    if(strcmp(array[i],array[j])>0){ 
        strcpy(newArray[k++], array[j++]);
    }
    else{
        strcpy(newArray[k++], array[i++]);
    }
}

while(i<=last1){            
    strcpy(newArray[k++], array[i++]);
}

while(j<=last2){
    strcpy(newArray[k++], array[j++]);
}

for(i=first1,j=0;j<k;i++,j++){
    strcpy(array[i], newArray[j]);
}
```

}

```
void mergeSort(char array[100][15],int first,int last){ 
int middle;
if(first<last){
    middle=(first+last)/2;
    mergeSort(array,first,middle);
    mergeSort(array,middle+1,last);
    merge(array,first,middle+1,middle,last); 
}
```

}

```
void sortCities(EXPEDITION *expedition, int expeditionNumber){
int i;
int j;
char tmp[100][15];

for(i=0,j=0;i<expeditionNumber;i++,j++){
    strcpy(tmp[j],expedition[i].city);
}

mergeSort(tmp,0,expeditionNumber);
for(i=0;i<expeditionNumber;i++){
    printf("%s\n",tmp[i]);
}
```

}